# How to deploy aspnet core app on linx docker container without getting 404 error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kestrel

I've got a ASPNET Core 5.0 web api app running successfully locally on Windows but failing when deployed to linux docker container which is hosted on linux server.  Page won't load when navigating to http://internal.apps.talquinelectric.com/is/api.  I'm getting a 404 error.

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:80",
      "sslPort": 80
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "FixBatchAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://internal.apps.talquinelectric.com/is/api",
      "applicationUrl": "http://internal.apps.talquinelectric.com/is/api",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "FixBatchAPI v1"));
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                        
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
  COPY FixBatchAPI/net50/ App/
  WORKDIR /App
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FixBatchAPI.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
   fixbatch-api:
      image: "fixbatch-api-build:latest"
      container_name: "fixbatch-api"
      networks:
        - traefix_proxy
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
 
        - "traefik.http.routers.fixbatch-api.entrypoint=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.fixbatch-api.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.fixbatch-api.rule=Host(`internal.apps.talquinelectric.com`) && PathPrefix(`/is/api`)"
        - "traefik.http.services.fixbatch-api-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.fixbatch-api-middlewares.chain.middlewares=fixbatch-api-strip"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.fixbatch-api-strip.stripprefix.prefixes=/is/api"

        - "traefik.http.routers.fixbatch-api-http.entrypoint=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.fixbatch-api-http.rule=Host(`internal.apps.talquinelectric.com`) && PathPrefix(`/is/api`)"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.fixbatch-api-redirect-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.fixbatch-api-http.middlewares=fixbatch-api-redirect-https"

        - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolalloworigin=*"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.addvaryheader=true"

networks:
   traefik_proxy:
      external: true
   default:
      external: false
```

Result of docker-compose logs:

[image: docker-compose-logs]

What I get when viewing in browser:

[image: browser rendering of 404 response]

Comment: From the logs in the ASP.NET app, it doesn't look like the requests get through to it. When you run it successfully on Windows, do you also have Traefik in front of it?

Comment: (talquinelectric - interesting bunch.)

Comment: Hans, when running locally in Windows the app is not running behind Traefik.

Answer (score 0):

**Add code like below, you can open swaggerui page.**

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "FixBatchAPI v1"));
} 
// default, no below code
else {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "FixBatchAPI v1"));
}
```